# Excel add a sequential number to based on unique id column

Tags: excel

I have a column with an order id in that is created for each product ordered.

I would like to have a separate column that has numbers the transaction based on the order id. Eg.

Order Id | Transaction No.
12345      1
12345      1
12345      1
54321      2
54321      2

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that your Order Id is sorted, here is an easy solution:

```
=IF(A2=A3,A2,A2+1)
```

Note that you have to set the very first transaction number in cell A2.

Comment: If it is not sorted then keep a list of unique Order Ids and incremental transaction numbers on a hidden worksheet or somewhere else out of the way and just use a vlookup.

Comment: That would be a way but we could also use array formulas to handle this (but I didn't want to use a heavy solution for an easy case)

Comment: When I get the data the transaction field will be blank. It is just the Order ID that I will have. I can sort this like you say. I have Order Id in Col A and Transaction Number in Col C. Can't quite get it to work though.

Comment: Okay got it to work with a tweak. 

=IF(A2=A1,C1,C1+1)

Comment: Glad it worked. Btw, welcome to stackoverflow, if this answer fits you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234 for more information